# Why I can use immediate evaluation ${bean.property} with writable property?

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish, el, mojarra

I understand that should not work according to [JEE6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html).

```
<h:inputText value="${bean.name}/>
```

and managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

But it work perfectly and I can read the 'name' property from the response page. I thought it only work with deferred evaluation #{expr} for writable properties.

Comment: You're completely mixing "reading" with "writing". Add a submit button and press it. Does the `${}` update (write) the model value? That's your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JEE6 tutorial:

> - Rvalue expressions can read data but cannot write it.
> - All expressions that are evaluated immediately use the ${} delimiters and are always rvalue expressions

So that may lead you to think that you can't use `${}` in a writable property, but if you read later:

> Where Value Expressions Can Be Used: Value expressions using the
>   ${} delimiters can be used in:
>
> - Static text
> - Any standard or custom tag attribute that can accept an expression

So, if I'm not mistaken, this doesn't contradict the former. It just means that when you use `<h:inputText value="${bean.name}"/>` it will be used to read the `name` property, but **it won't write** it if you modify the content in the `inputText`.